# Getting exception in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am practicing spring boot. i have downloaded spring boot code from git repo and imported it on InteliJ idea. while executing the spring boot application I am getting below exception. do you have any idea about this? this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>rc</groupId>
    <artifactId>note-it-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>noteit</name>
    <!-- <text>Demo project for Spring Boot</text>-->

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>10</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFa

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0 and Spring 5.0 aren't supported on Java11. Spring 5.1 and Spring Boot 2.1 are.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, which java version should i use for this spring code

Comment: Java 8 til 10 should do. Remove the java compiler plugin as well from your configuration.

Comment: Hope this will help: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Your Database settings to application.properties, because You are using Spring-Data-JPA, 
 for example:

```
# JPA (JpaBaseConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration)
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default # Bootstrap mode for JPA repositories.
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true # Whether to enable JPA repositories.
spring.jpa.database= # Target database to operate on, auto-detected by default. Can be alternatively set using the "databasePlatform" property.
spring.jpa.database-platform= # Name of the target database to operate on, auto-detected by default. Can be alternatively set using the "Database" enum.
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false # Whether to initialize the schema on startup.
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= # DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property. Defaults to "create-drop" when using an embedded database and no schema manager was detected. Otherwise, defaults to "none".
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy= # Fully qualified name of the implicit naming strategy.
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy= # Fully qualified name of the physical naming strategy.
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings= # Whether to use Hibernate's newer IdentifierGenerator for AUTO, TABLE and SEQUENCE.
spring.jpa.mapping-resources= # Mapping resources (equivalent to "mapping-file" entries in persistence.xml).
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true # Register OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor. Binds a JPA EntityManager to the thread for the entire processing of the request.
spring.jpa.properties.*= # Additional native properties to set on the JPA provider.
spring.jpa.show-sql=false # Whether to enable logging of SQL statements.
```

Set database, database-platform, or just delete spring-data-jpa from your pom.xml

Comment: Yes. If you adding JPA dependency, you need to add database configurations as well.

Comment: thanks deinum , janath, Rafalsonn for your response. i tried to download java 10, but it is no longer available, i have changed spring version in pom.xml to 2.1.0, but it is throwing below error

Comment: @SriniVasan Did you removed your JPA dependency or added the configuration to application.properties?

Comment: i have re-generated code using spring initializer for java 11 version and refactored code with existing API, now the issue is solved. Thanks to all for your support